# String split and extract the last field in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I have a text file `FILENAME`. I want to split the string at `-` of the first column field and extract the last element from each line. Here `"$(echo $line | cut -d, -f1 | cut -d- -f4)";` alone is not giving me the right result.

FILENAME:

```
TWEH-201902_Pau_EX_21-1195060301,15cef8a046fe449081d6fa061b5b45cb.final.cram
TWEH-201902_Pau_EX_22-1195060302,25037f17ba7143c78e4c5a475ee98e25.final.cram
TWEH-201902_Pau_T-1383-1195060311,267364a6767240afab2b646deec17a34.final.cram
```

code I tried:

```
while read line; do \
DNA="$(echo $line | cut -d, -f1 | cut -d- -f4)";
echo $DNA
done < ${FILENAME}
```

Result I want

```
1195060301
1195060302
1195060311
```

Comment: What result is it giving you the code right now?

Comment: For some lines, it is giving me empty. Because the `-f4` position is not available (only upto `-f3`) in some lines.

Comment: If you look at the third line, it has 4 fields while first two lines only have 3 fields delimited by `-`.

Comment: 1. Are all the numbers you are looking for going to be 10 or more digits long?

Comment: 2. Will there only ever be one 10-digit number per line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would you please try the following:

```
while IFS=, read -r f1 _; do    # set field separator to ",", assigns f1 to the 1st field and _ to the rest
    dna=${f1##*-}               # removes everything before the rightmost "-" from "$f1"
    echo "$dna"
done < "$FILENAME"
```

Comment: since you don't use `f2` it is good practice to use the placeholder variable `_` as: `while IFS=, read -r f1 _; do`

Comment: @LéaGris thanks! I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: To the OP, thank for accepting my answer. Answering your (possibly removed) question. please try `others=${f1%-*}` to obtain the opposite of `dna=${f1##*-}`, e.g. the substring `TWEH-201902_Pau_EX_21` for the 1st line.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know the constraints on your input file, but if what you are looking for is a 10-digit number, and there is only ever one 10-digit number per line... This should do niceley

```sh
grep -Eo '[0-9]{10,}' input.txt
```

```
1195060301
1195060302
1195060311
```

This essentially says: Show me all 10 digit numbers in this file

input.txt

```
TWEH-201902_Pau_EX_21-1195060301,15cef8a046fe449081d6fa061b5b45cb.final.cram
TWEH-201902_Pau_EX_22-1195060302,25037f17ba7143c78e4c5a475ee98e25.final.cram
TWEH-201902_Pau_T-1383-1195060311,267364a6767240afab2b646deec17a34.final.cram
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, I had to do with the two lines of codes. May be someone has a better approach.

```
while read line; do \
DNA="$(echo $line| cut -d, -f1| rev)"
DNA="$(echo $DNA| cut -d- -f1 | rev)"
echo $DNA
done < ${FILENAME}
```

Answer (score 0):

A `sed` approach:

```sh
sed -nE 's/.*-([[:digit:]]+)\,.*/\1/p' input_file
```

`sed` options:

- `-n`: Do not print the whole file back, but only explicit `/p`.
- `-E`: Use Extend Regex without need to escape its grammar.

`sed` Extended REgex:

- `'s/.*-([[:digit:]]+)\,.*/\1/p'`: Search, capture one or more digit in group 1, preceded by anything and a dash, followed by a comma and anything, and print only the captured group.

Answer (score 0):

Using awk:

```
awk -F[,] '{ split($1,arr,"-");print arr[length(arr)] }' FILENAME
```

Using , as a separator, take the first delimited "piece" of data and further split it into an arr using - as the delimiter and awk's split function. We then print the last index of arr.